Conversions no longer working in KDE Plasma launcher or KRunner
Converting for example temperatures
-5C in F

or currencies
5CAD to USD

and so on used to work in the KDE Start menu / launcher in 23.10 (mantic), but apparently no longer does after upgrading to 24.04 (noble).
Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround?

Could be this annoying bug once again?
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=441337

@Polemon Hmm, I've tried that now, but even after deleting ~/.local/share/libkunitconversion/currency.xml the conversions still don't work (either before or after logging in/out)

Apparently, this new syntax works:
5CAD -> USD=


That is the most cumbersome syntax anybody could come up with.
